# Emacs: move to a certain character, forwards and backwards

Tags: emacs

In vim, I can use `f` to move the cursor forwards to a certain character and `F` to do this backwards. How to do it in Emacs? I know you can use `C-z` or `M-z` to delete until a certain character, and you can also first delete then paste to achieve a motion. But 1) is there a better way to do this, only movement, without delete? and 2) how to do this backwards?

Comment: While [ace jump](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AceJump) is not exactly the same, you may want to check it out.

Comment: @Tom checkout [jump-char](https://github.com/lewang/jump-char), which addresses this specific need along with `ace-jump-mode` integration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Forward incremental search is C-s, and reverse incremental search is C-r.

Responding to comment:

To delete from the current position backwards to a specific character, you can use

C-<space> to mark the current position, then C-r <char> <RET> to locate the search character, and C-w to delete between current position and mark.

To get more help on doing things in emacs, you should look at the tutorial.  Typing C-h t will open the tutorial in a new buffer.

Comment: Thanks. How can I delete backwards until a certain character? Say I have "abcd|efg", "|" being the cursor. How to delete "bcd"?

Comment: With a negative argument to `C-z`, e.g. `C-u - 1 C-z`.

Comment: Of course, you can bind it to some key if you thing it's too convoluted to press which it is.

Comment: @Tom "convoluted" is always redundant when talking about keystrokes in emacs. ;)

Comment: I agree the defaults are often horrible, only some oldtime emacs users think they are well thought out and convenient to use. I recommend everyone to rebind the default bindings mercilessly according to one's own personal preferences.

Comment: 'C-<space> to mark the current position, ' part is redundant, Emacs does "Mark saved where search started" as after <RET>.

Answer (score 9):

[jump-char](https://github.com/lewang/jump-char) was designed specifically for this task.

To delete, use `zap-to-char` or activate the mark by pressing <kbd>C-spc</kbd> before jumping, then <kbd>C-w</kbd>.

Comment: There is no need to activate the mark actually, it works without C-spc.

Answer (score 0):

I use `iy-go-to-char`, as in the *Emacs Rocks!* [screencast](http://emacsrocks.com/e04.html) which demonstrates its use.

I like how it does not highlight all occurrences of the character in the buffer, not distracting you and making it the fastest option.

I personally use the `iy-go-up-to-char` version to have it stop *before* the targeted character.

Example shortcut (*iy-go-to-char* is on MELPA):

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-m") 'iy-go-up-to-char) 
;; Move point to next occurrence of char. Can start typing immediately.`

Answer (score -3):

For **Searching** i often use : 
<kbd>`Ctrl-s`</kbd>
For **Navigation** :
<kbd>`Alt-f`</kbd> - moving one word forward or you can use  <kbd>`Ctrl-f`</kbd> for moving one character forward.
<kbd>`Alt-b`</kbd> - moving one word backward or you can use <kbd>`Ctrl-b`</kbd> for moving one character backward. 
For more reference you can use  [Emacs Cheatsheet](http://www.cs.iupui.edu/~kweimer/EmacsCheatSheet.pdf).

Comment: That Emacs Cheatsheet link is broken